# I can't make an edge sharp

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm new to Blender and I wanted to design this mask in order to print it in 3D but i have a problem.
I want the eyes holes to be sharp but the subdivision surface modifier make them round.
I tried everything i found on internet to make them sharp ( edge split, ctrl r, crease... ) but none of them works.
Could you please help me ?
Thank you.

[image: My work]

I want it to look like this : [image]

Comment: The edge that should crease are the one that you'll make by solidifying the surface, so at the moment crease can't help you. You should be able to refine the geometry by adding vertex or loopcuts in the interested areas. You can even apply the subsurf modifier and then tweak the wrong vertex position if your goal is 3D printing only. There many to achieve similar results, could you better define what your goals and workflow are?

Comment: First i would like to thank you to take the time to help me. My goal is to print it at a " face " scale, and make an awesome cosplay of a jedi temple guard, but my only problems are those eyes holes that won't sharpen.

Comment: I've tried to add vertex but i can only do it under the hole and not on the sides so it only sharpen only one side of the eye.

Comment: This looks like something the Edge Split modifier would fix.  I can't imagine why it wouldn't.  Maybe order of operations makes a difference?  Try to use it before your mirror modifier, and see if there's any difference that way.

Comment: Unfortunately edge split doesnt work, is there a way i can send you the file so you can see ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have geometry that can follow an edge loop you can make edges as sharp as you want. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> is the hotkey for creating loops in Edit Mode. Loops require quads. Below I have the example to start...

[image]

...and then adding an extra loop to sharpen even more.

[image]

I did cheat a bit here as the loops do cross - but it still works and I think acceptable.

[image]