# Modeling sharp edge problem

Tags: modeling, edges

I am struggling to model clean sharp edges on a dress I have designed in blender. I have attached a photo with circles marking the sharp edges that aren't looking to great or sharp.[image] [image]

Here is the blender file: [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this should help here too https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76892/i-cant-make-an-edge-sharp/76912#76912

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of what you are showing in the first image is caused by extra geometry you have in the mesh. Before following Patdogs suggestion you should first sort that out.

Use the Delete > Delete Vertice tool on the 2 inside faces and the Delete > **Disolve Vertice** tool of the rest.

[image]

Then use the knife tool to add back some now missing edges.

[image]